# Does "three corner" refer to South Australia?

Tags: slang, australian-english

In the NHK program [Somewhere Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somewhere_Street) (Japanese: Sekai Fureai Machiaruki) on Adelaide, a lifesaver was quoted as saying what sounded like ([pideo.net link](http://www.pideo.net/video/youku/2b5fa5dfd1568737/) at 14:25):

> Born down the road ... after going to the other states, it's pretty
>   busy inter-state, so it's nice to come back and live the three corner
>   pace, very nice

Does "three corner" refer to South Australia, with the North West, North East and South West (?) corners being the three corners?

**Edit:** Maybe I'm mistaken, and the guy is saying "three quarter pace".

Comment: I'd go with 'three quarter pace' after listening to the video several times (mentioned at 14:28).  The swelling final music of the program drowns it out somewhat, but both the 'qu' and 't' are clear, and after living here (Australia) for fifty years I'm fairly familiar with the accent.  There are Australian expressions that reference the pace of life in various parts of Australia.  Most of these though are linked to Northern Australia - such as 'Broome Time' or '(Torres Strait) Island Time' - and signify a very slow pace indeed.  But in this case it seems to be simply a quantitive observation,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a mishearing of spoken English

Answer (score 1):

Nix. It refers to the place where Queensland, New South Wales and South Australia meet. A photo of the corner of the dingo fence there is available at http://nla.gov.au/nla.pic-vn3506807. Also known as Cameron Corner, this inviting area

> ... is an especially remote and hostile environment. Travel in summer is best avoided as the flies are intolerable, the heat unbearable, and the risk of dehydration very real. Autumn through to spring is much more appropriate, but travellers arriving in winter should be prepared for cold nights.

[Australia Adventures (web site)](http://www.australiaadventures.com/cornercountry.htm)